# Converting a PIL.Image to wagtailimages.Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wagtail

I am creating a thumbnail for the images with Pillow, however I can't store them in the field image_thumbnail because the field is of type Image and I am getting an exception: ValueError: Cannot assign "": "GalleryItem.image_thumbnail" must be a "Image" instance.

Wagtail is using Pillow already but I cannot find an easy way to do it...

```
 class GalleryItem(models.Model):
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        help_text='Image size must be 1440 x 961 px.'
    )
    image_thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        'ImageCategorie',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    def createThumbnails(self):
        size = (300, 300)
        outfile = self.image.title.split('.')[0] + ".thumbnail.jpg"
        try:
            im = Image.open(self.image.file)
            im.thumbnail(size)
            im.save(outfile, format="jpeg")
            return im
        except IOError:
            print("cannot create thumbnail for", self.image.file)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.image_thumbnail = self.createThumbnails()
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
        super(GalleryItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conceptually, PIL.Image and wagtailimages.Image are two different things: PIL.Image represents an image file (i.e. a specific bunch of pixels), while wagtailimages.Image is a database record for "a picture" as a piece of selectable and reusable editorial content, with supporting metadata (usually just title, but [other fields](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/advanced_topics/images/custom_image_model.html#custom-image-models) are possible too) and the ability to re-render it at any size. Using wagtailimages.Image to store a thumbnailed version of an existing image is overkill, and you're probably better off making the `image_thumbnail` field a Django [`ImageField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) (which stores an image in the "bunch of pixels" sense).

If you really want to use wagtailimages.Image here, you can, but you'll need to create the database record for the image and *then* attach it to your GalleryItem object. The code will be something like:

```
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image as PILImage
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from wagtail.images.models import Image as WagtailImage

...
    pil_image = PILImage.open(self.image.file)
    pil_image.thumbnail(size)
    f = BytesIO()
    pil_image.save(f, 'JPEG')

    wagtail_image = WagtailImage.objects.create(
        title=('thumbnail of %s' % self.image.title),
        file=ImageFile(f, name=outfile)
    )
    self.image_thumbnail = wagtail_image
```

Answer (score 0):

Before seeing gasman's answer I succeeded with the below code:

```
def createThumbnails(self):
        # Set our max thumbnail size in a tuple (max width, max height)
        THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (200, 200)
        outfile = self.image.title.split('.')[0] + ".thumbnail.jpg"
        extention = self.image.filename.split('.')[1]
        img_io = BytesIO()
        PIL_TYPE = 'jpeg'
        try:
            # Open original photo which we want to thumbnail using PIL's Image
            im = PILImage.open(BytesIO(self.image.file.read()))
            im.thumbnail(THUMBNAIL_SIZE, PILImage.ANTIALIAS)
            im.save(img_io, PIL_TYPE)
            img_io.seek(0)
            # Save image to a SimpleUploadedFile which can be saved into
            # ImageField
            suf = SimpleUploadedFile(outfile, img_io.read())
            self.screenshot.save(outfile, suf, save=False)
        except IOError:
            print("cannot create thumbnail for", self.image.file)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.createThumbnails()
        super(GalleryItem, self).save(force_update=False)
```